# Mirror Application from Windows to TV?

Tags: open-source, windows-7, networking, display

I have a device called **AnyCAST HDMI** this one:

[image]

I already plugged it into my TV. And it appeared like this:

[image]

And then i tried to use AirMyPC installed inside my Windows 7 computer.
Luckily everything works well for mirroring and it's succesfully displayed on the TV.

But after the trial time ended. I look arround as an alternative in opensource app. But found nothing.

My purpose is to get the same app just like AirMyPC that works without need of installing another (software receiver on tv). And of course open source means "no trial". Does anyone have experienced this?

Comment: just a hint... open source does not mean gratis, just free: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre

Comment: he,.... thanks @DJCrashdummy,.. have u used airmirroring device?